# Check if column values exists in different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame 'df' with x rows, and another pandas DataFrame 'df2' with y rows
(x < y). I want to return the indexes of where the values of df['Farm'] equals the value of df2['Fields'], in order to add respective 'Manager' to df.

the code I have is as follows:

```
data2 = [['field1', 'Paul G'] , ['field2', 'Mark R'], ['field3', 'Roy Jr']]
data = [['field1'] , ['field2']]
columns = ['Field']
columns2 = ['Field', 'Manager']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=columns2)

farmNames = df['Farm']
exists = farmNames.reset_index(drop=True) == df1['Field'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

This returns the error message:

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: That sounds like a [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes! I want to use a boolean series 'exists' to merge another column (say 'Manager') in df2, into df

Comment: Not sure what you mean - could you post two example input dataframes for df1 and df2, plus the output? They don't need to be big. In fact, the smaller the better as long as it shows the problem.

Comment: I edited the original question with your request

Answer (score 1):

As @NickODell mentioned, you could use a merge, basically a left join. See below code.

```
df_new = pd.merge(df, df2, on = 'Field', how = 'left')
print(df_new)
```

**Output:**

```
    Field Manager
0  field1  Paul G
1  field2  Mark R
```

Comment: oh wow, another reason to love python i guess. Thanks!